# Rails paperclip with s3 - Invalid argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I set up an app with use of Paperclip to cover user avatar's issue. I want to store files on amazon s3. I cannot find a solution for this problem so finally I decided to ask here:

Here is connection setup in user model:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
:styles => { :small => "150x150#", :medium => "300x300#" },
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => Rails.root.join('config/s3.yml')
```

Then here is s3.yml file:

```
bucket: sghub      
access_key_id: ###
secret_access_key: #####
```

Of course in my gemfile I have added:

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
```

The app is deployed on Heroku so the error I get from `heroku logs` command is like this:

```
2012-02-20T07:13:58+00:00 app[web.1]: AWS::S3::PermanentRedirect (The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.)
```

Also in development mode the error page is like:

```
Errno::EINVAL in UsersController#update
Invalid argument
```

Also it appears that files doesn't upload on s3, as they are not visible in management console in my bucket. I have pretty much no idea now as I tried to set up everything like in all tutorials and documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:bucket` option should live outside of the `:s3_credentials` key in the options hash. Make it look like so:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
    :styles         => { :small => "150x150#", :medium => "300x300#" },
    :storage        => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join('config/s3.yml')
    :bucket         => 'sghub'
```

And remove `bucket` from `config/s3.yml`

Here are the docs: http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3

Comment: I think the problem was with configuration of European Amazon s3 server because in paperclip default is US server. Otherwise your tip helped me to find it out. Thank you very much!